# Is it possible to find a python package's path from the command line?

Tags: python, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I know in ruby you can do.

```
gem path filename
```

in the terminal when you gem install 'gem-path'and in python you can do

```
>>> import os
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(os)
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.pyc'
>>> inspect.getfile(inspect)
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/inspect.pyc'
>>> os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(inspect))
'/usr/lib64/python2.7'
```

within the python shell, but can you do anything like the ruby version with python?

I'm using xubuntu if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3):

use the following

```
pip show package-name
```

For example:

```
C:\Users\User>pip show numpy
---
Name: numpy
Version: 1.9.2
Location: c:\python34\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `inspect` itself

```
$ python -m inspect -d os 

Target: os
Origin: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/os.py
Cached: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/__pycache__/os.cpython-34.pyc
Loader: <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10a504a58>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the package is installed by pip:

```
$ pip show pep8
---
Name: pep8
Version: 1.6.2
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

You have to add the `/pep8[/|.py|.pyc]` to the location yourself.

From the interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pep8
>>> pep8
<module 'pep8' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pep8.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ python -c "import pip; print(pip.__path__[0].rstrip('/pip'))"
/path/to/site-packages
```